# Vue3/Quasar2: Layout's "oMounted" is invoked, even though only the child route is called - why?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, quasar

In my little app I want to use at least 2 layouts, important part being that there shall be animations once a route is entered / left. In the "MainLayout" (`https://[domain]/catalog-of-works`) the  menu is constructed: whenever a link is clicked there, a child template is supposed to be loaded("(`https://[domain]/catalog-of-works/:category`).

The problem is that whenever a child element (the "nested route") is loaded, a "complete route change" is detected and invokes "onMounted" of "MainLayout", too.
This is not what I want to achieve. Instead, the `onMounted` and `onLeave` lifecycle hooks of "MainLayout" should only be invoked, when the main domain "https://[domain]/catalog" is left and changes to another domain (e.g. "https://[domain]/" or "https://[domain]/books").

I put together a really ugly template here on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-enyltx?file=src%2Flayouts%2FMainLayout.vue

A little red square fading in at the top left indicates that the "onMounted" method is called, whenever another catalog category is invoked. (Also, see console, where "onBeforeAppear", "onAppear" and "onMounted" are logged).
But, as mentioned: this is not what I want. The square (and therefore the menu) shall only "react" on first load and on leave.

Any idea what I have to do to fix this?

For conveniance, here is the content of `routes.js`:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/StartpageLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/IndexPage.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/main',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/MainPage.vue'),
        children: [
          {
            path: 'subsite-one',
            component: () => import('pages/main/SubsiteOnePage.vue.vue')
          },
          {
            path: 'subsite-two',
            component: () => import('pages/main/SubsiteTwoPage.vue.vue')
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/catalog-of-works',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: ':category',
        component: () => import('pages/catalog/CatalogOfWorks.vue'),
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/startpage/home',
    redirect: '/'
  },
  // Always leave this as last one, but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/PageNotFound.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used your Mainlayout twice.
You have to use it once so that the onMounted hook will only run once the MainLayout is mounted.

```
{
path: '/main',
component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: () => import('pages/MainPage.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subsite-one',
        component: () => import('pages/main/SubsiteOnePage.vue.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'subsite-two',
        component: () => import('pages/main/SubsiteTwoPage.vue.vue')
      },

      //Work routes
      {
        path: '/catalog-of-works',
        component: () => import('pages/catalog/CatalogOfWorks.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: '/catalog-of-works/:category',
        component: () => import('pages/catalog/CatalogOfWorks.vue'),
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

},

Comment: Thank you fo your quick response! I really thought layouts are reusable!! Anyway, I removed it, the "onMounted" is nevertheless called on each child route change. SO this does not seem to be the problem...